# OptionsMenu from Fragment in ViewPager freezes after displaying child DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have an Activity with ViewPager that contains 4 fragments. In one of the fragments that displays contacts I added OptionsMenu with SearchView action.

Initialy everything works great, OptionsMenu is visible when that specific fragment is loaded, but as soon as a child DialogFragment is shown OptionsMenu fails to refresh. If some DialogFragment is opened on Contacts Fragment (the one with OptionsMenu) then the MenuItem stays visible everywhere in the app. If some DialogFragment is opened from other parts of the app, then the MenuItem stays hidden even if user navigates back to the Contacts Fragment. What am I missing?

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)  
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.contacts_menu, menu)
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
}

override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
    menu?.let {
        val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search)
        setupSearchView(searchItem)
    }
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    return when (item?.itemId) {
        R.id.search -> {
            item.expandActionView()
            true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}

private fun setupSearchView(searchItem: MenuItem) {
    val searchView = searchItem.actionView as SearchView
    val clearButton = searchView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.search_close_btn)

    val searchViewLayoutParams = searchView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.search_edit_frame).layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams
    searchViewLayoutParams.leftMargin = 0

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            query?.let {
                if(query.isBlank()) {
                    showProperContacts(RESTORE_CONTACTS)
                } else {
                    showProperContacts(query = it)
                }
            }
            return false
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(query: String?): Boolean {
            query?.let {
                showProperContacts(query = it)
            }
            return false
        }
    })

    searchItem.setOnActionExpandListener(object: MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener {
        override fun onMenuItemActionExpand(item: MenuItem?): Boolean = true

        override fun onMenuItemActionCollapse(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
            showProperContacts(RESTORE_CONTACTS)
            animateFilter(true)
            return true
        }

    })

    clearButton.setOnClickListener {
        searchView.setQuery("", true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your `showProperContacts` or `animateFilter` call to invalidate options menu?

Comment: @Aaron no, it doesn't call invalidateOptionsMenu